# Position: fixed ignored in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-position

I ran across a problem with Chrome where position:fixed is not fixed. There may be something I'm doing wrong, but this works in FF and Safari, but not Chrome (69.0.3497.100). In Chrome, the blue div moves and the green becomes visible when scrolling around the page, but FF and Safari will not scroll and the green is always hidden. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to get real position: fixed in Chrome?

```css
div {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
    body {
      background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I opened this post in chrome and when the snippet is fullscreen, it works, but when I make a new html file and open that directly, the bug appears again.

```
<html>
   <body>
     <div></div>
     <style>
      div {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        background-color: blue;
      }
      body {
        background-color: green;
      }
     </style>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include any information needed. I can't reproduce this on the latest version of Chrome on Windows 10 Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Did you make a .html file and open that? The snippet does not show it.

Comment: Yes, putting the `style` in the `head` as is customary, and copying your HTML verbatim.

Comment: I just tried with the newest chrome freshly downloaded as of four minutes ago and it doesn't work on macOS El Capitan

Comment: I'm running Chrome 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) on MacOS Mojave, no problems.

Comment: Also tested in Firefox, FF Dev Edition, and Opera. No problems. Seems to be just you.

Comment: Here's a screen recording... I can't figure out what's happening. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BoVGxQtx8njuzNwbUbNq4D7FQOuEJr3O/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: LOL... that's how Mac works. Chrome does it, FF doesn't. It's called something scrolling, it basically shows a bit of edges if you scroll.

Comment: I got a screencast of it happening... it's normal and nothing you can do about it. https://monosnap.com/file/UmOJAEa91Dn9UYYTaXgOjNA9I6rsEN

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all, it's better to put the style tag on the head of the document. Then, your div does not have any width and height. Try giving your body 100vw width and 200vh height, then give your fixed div 100px width and 100px height. You will see it work. Also you will have to decide between top:0 and bottom:0, and also decide between right:0 and left:0

Comment: I assume you meant 100% not 100px because I want this to fill the page and why 200vh?

Comment: i didnt realize you wanted to fill the page. 200vh is to expand the parent so that you can have a scroll effect and see it work. So, if you want to have a div filling the page you can go with 100vw and 100vh on your div.

Comment: To clarify, it should *not* scroll.